# MVC Razor Set value of TextBoxFor from Button Group

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to set the value of a textboxfor control from a button group. 
1/ I am not sure how to refer to the texboxfor, I have tried EqType.Value = 2

```
<script>
    $(".btn-group > .btnEqType").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
       EqType.Value = 2
    });

</script>

 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="agd2">Set ID</label>
   <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.eType, new { @class = "input k-textbox", id = "EqType", Value = "3" })
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: `$('#EqType').val('2');` But why are you changing the default `id` attribute (which would have been `id="eType"`) to `id="EqType"`? And your should never set the `value` attribute in the html helper!

Comment: And what do you think `<label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="agd2">Set ID</label>` is doing - you don't have a control with `id="agd2"`

Comment: did you try $('#EqType').val('2');

Comment: You don't need to set the id attribute for the `textboxfor` helper. As its extension method automatically does it for name and ID. So name==id in this case

Comment: Sorry I was not very clear. What I wan  to do is get the value of the button pressed from the btn-group. So in the group I want to retrieve the ID. I can get the name of the value like this, how do I get the ID value?  document.getElementById('EqType').value = this.innerHTML;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing like this...

```
          <script>
           $(".btn-group > .btnEqType").click(function () {
           $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
           document.getElementById('EqType').value = $(this).attr("id");
            })
```

Answer (score 2):

Read up on jQuery selectors http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

```
<script>
    $(".btn-group > .btnEqType").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
        $('#EqType').val("2");
    });

</script>
```

Try debugging your jQuery in Chrome developer tools. On the webpage press F12 and then go to the console. Type in  `$('#EqType')` and see what is returned.